# On the smallest field containing two other fields

Tags: field-theory

While studying Field Theory I came across a doubt about a theorem about the direct limit of fields. When I asked my teacher about it, he told me to think about it this way...

Consider $E_1, E_2$ fields such that $C=E_1\cap E_2$ and $D=E_1\cup E_2$. Generally the set $D$ is not a field. Now, consider the polynomial forms with coefficients over $C$ with variables $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha\in E_1\setminus C$ and $\beta\in E_2\setminus C$.

$$P_C[\alpha,\beta]=\{f(\alpha,\beta), \alpha\in E_1\setminus C\,\land\,\beta\in E_2\setminus C\}$$

I had no difficulties proving that this is a field. First I showed that it was a ring, then I found inverses.

I was told to prove that $P_C[\alpha,\beta]$ is the smallest field containing $D$. What I did was to prove $D\subseteq P_C[\alpha,\beta]$.

To do this I considered wlog that $\gamma\in E_1$, then there are two cases:

- $\gamma\in C$ implies $\gamma$ is constant and we are done.
- Otherwise we can set $\gamma := \alpha$ and $\beta=0$. In this way we arrive at the conclusion.

Hence $D\subseteq P_C[\alpha,\beta]$.

Now, how can I prove the other inclusion i.e. $P_C[\alpha,\beta] \subseteq D$?

Comment: $C = E_1 \cap E_2$. Assume $E_1 = C(a_1,\ldots,a_n), E_2 = C(b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ (finitely generated extensions) then $E_1E_2 = C(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ is the smallest field containing $E_1,E_2$. It really doesn't say more than that. If the $a_i,b_j$ are algebraic over $C$ then $E_1 = C[a_1,\ldots,a_n], E_2 = C[b_1,\ldots,b_m], E_1E_2 = C[a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m]$.

Comment: It's not true that $P_C[\alpha,\beta]$ is a field in general...I don't know how you think you showed it has inverses.

Comment: The inclusion you want to prove is almost always false.